# Why is this index route raising RecordNotFound in deployment but works perfectly in development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails app I have an index route that is working perfectly in development, but when pushed to deployment is raising an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error.

I am having trouble finding a systematic way to debug this because (a) I don't understand why an index would raise RecordNotFound; (b) the route works perfectly in development; and (c) I'm unsure where I should be looking to get useful logs/ reports from deployment to see what is going on.

The route in question:

```
#routes.rb
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
  scope module: :v2, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 2, default: :true) do
    resources :states
  end
end
```

In development navigating to `/api/states` hits the api/v2/states controller and returns the correct output.

In deployment the same URL is hitting

```
#application_controller.rb
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :record_not_found
```

I tried adding some debug code to api_states_controller

```
def index 
   Rails.logger.info @states
   # .....
end
```

But of course this action is not being hit in deployment.

I also tried adding debug code to `:record_not_found`

```
def record_not_found
  Rails.logger.info 'We are here'
  flash[:alert] = "That page doesn't exist!"
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

Which is being raised, but I have not been able to find any variables available here that are telling me anything useful.

Why would an index be available in development, but raise `RecordNotFound` in deployment? And what is a sensible way to examine this problem?

Log output

```
Processing by Api::V2::StatesController#index as JSON
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 681]]
  Role Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles"."id" = "roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "roles_users"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 681]]
  State Load (18.3ms)  SELECT "states".* FROM "states" WHERE (name ilike '%%')  ORDER BY states.name ASC OFFSET 0
[active_model_serializers]   Event Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."state_id" = $1 [["state_id", 474]]
[active_model_serializers]   Country Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" INNER JOIN "regions" ON "countries"."id" = "states"."country_id" WHERE "states"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 475]]
```

Comment: Do you have any `before_action` for that controller?

Comment: yes `before_action :set_resource, only: [:destroy, :show, :update]` which is basiclaly doing a `find(params[:id])`. However, it should not be triggered on the index action.

Comment: Could you try to visit the url in your development env, and see are there any queries being fired? It won't make sense that only prod has the query, and dev not.

Comment: yes, some queries are being fired. I have posted some examples to the question. This app has a Country, State and City model. The country API is working fine, but both State and City are raising this `not found` error. The only difference I can see is that fewer queries are being run with Country, but none of these should be raising an error.

Comment: I put more comments in an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned under question's comments, you need to make sure all the db  queries should be run just fine.

And since you rescued from `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception, that might be kind of hard to tell from the log of what's going wrong. Two ways to debug this:

1). I would suggest you do this, put `Rails.logger.info xxx` before anywhere that may have a db query. eg, you will query for user's roles, states by matching names, state events, states' countries. Based on the log output, there are 5 queries being fired, make sure to find out which query goes wrong and why.

2). Remove the `rescue_from`, and the log will just show you what query went wrong.

As to the question itself, yes it's running great in development, but since they have different dbs, then the only thing that might be wrong is data.

You could try to connect to production database in your development env and debug.

Comment: Thanks @Larry Lv, you are absolutely right. I removed the `rescue_from` temporarily, and this showed that an invalid record had crept into the database. Fixing this record (and improving validations!) fixed this error.